# How do I show elements that have start date in one month and end date in another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am trying to only show elements that are related to certain months.  I am using PHP to make a select box that value's are the months' first and last days of the month.

Here is the resulting HTML for the select box:

```
<select id="month" name="monthdaterange">
    <option value="1427864400,1430370000">April</option>
    <option value="1430456400,1433048400">May</option>
    <option value="1433134800,1435640400">June</option>
    <option value="1435726800,1438318800">July</option>
    <option value="1438405200,1440997200">August</option>
    <option value="1441083600,1443589200">September</option>
    <option value="1443675600,1446267600">October</option>
    <option value="1446354000,1448863200">November</option>
    <option value="1448949600,1451541600">December</option>
    <option value="1451628000,1454220000">January</option>
    <option value="1454306400,1456725600">February</option>
    <option value="1456812000,1459400400">March</option>
</select>
```

This is one related element:

```
<div data-start-date="1429765200" data-end-date="1431061200" class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns special-container">
    <div class="special-block">
        <div class="special-block-text">
            <h3>Special Test 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am using `data-start-date` and `data-end-date` to store the start and end date of the element.

Then I am using jQuery to compare the element date range to the select box values.

```
function get_month_specials(mnth){
    var daterange = mnth.split(',');
    var firstofmonth = daterange[0];
    var lastofmonth = daterange[1];
    //alert('The start date of this month is: ' + firstofmonth + '. The end date of this month is: ' + lastofmonth);

    jQuery('.special-container').each( function( index, value ){
        if(jQuery(this).attr('data-start-date') >= firstofmonth || jQuery(this).attr('data-end-date') <= lastofmonth){
            jQuery(this).css( 'background-color', '#fff' );
        }
    });
}
```

The issue I am having is with the above element.  It has a start date in April and an end date in May.  This means it should be displayed in both months when selected.  But instead it only displays in April. What am I missing to make it so elements that have a date range between two or more months display when any of those months are selected?

Here is a Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBLwwv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logic is wrong, try this

```
$('.special-container').each( function( index, value ){
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
    if(
      ($(this).attr('data-start-date') >= firstofmonth && $(this).attr('data-start-date') <= lastofmonth) ||
      ($(this).attr('data-end-date') <= lastofmonth && $(this).attr('data-end-date') >= firstofmonth)) {
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Edited: final fix: "looks" both way

```
$('.special-container').each( function( index, value ){
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
  if( 
     (firstofmonth >= $(this).attr('data-start-date') && firstofmonth <= $(this).attr('data-end-date')) || 
     (lastofmonth >= $(this).attr('data-start-date') && lastofmonth <= $(this).attr('data-end-date')) ||
     ($(this).attr('data-start-date') >= firstofmonth && $(this).attr('data-start-date') <= lastofmonth)
  ) {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEzZvw

Comment: I tried using this, but if the date of the special is say April 1, 2015 to April1, 2016 the special only shows in April rather than on any selection.

Comment: Can you provide the sample for that special date?

Comment: $('.special-container').each( function( index, value ){
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
      if(
        (firstofmonth >= $(this).attr('data-start-date') && firstofmonth <= $(this).attr('data-end-date')) ||
        (lastofmonth >= $(this).attr('data-start-date')  && lastofmonth <= $(this).attr('data-end-date'))) {
          $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      }
  });

Comment: Here is the Codepen that I added your code from the comment and the other examples.  I still don't see the behavior I am seeking. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPeNvM

Comment: There is something wrong with those timestamp vs text, double check first that

Comment: Also on Codepen you have two For Each

Comment: That last Codepen seemed to do the trick! If you want to edit your answer with the updated code I will mark your answer as the correct one.  Thank you so much for the help with this!

Answer (score 2):

If you're only bothered about if it is in that month then just use the start dates of the month.

Change this line

```
if(jQuery(this).attr('data-start-date') >= firstofmonth || jQuery(this).attr('data-end-date') >= lastofmonth){
```

To

```
if(jQuery(this).attr('data-start-date') >= firstofmonth || jQuery(this).attr('data-end-date') >= firstofmonth ){
```

It doesn't matter when the month ends you just need to know if the event is ongoing past the 1st of the month

Comment: Thank you this seems to be doing the trick, After looking at it I had it set up for this logic anyway but I seemed to confuse that I needed the lastofmonth.

Comment: Upon further testing this isn't working 100% yet.  If I have an special only in July, it is showing when April, May, June, and July are selected?  I only would want that special to show in July.  Any ideas?